# Xcode: objective c cannot call a method from another class

Tags: xcode, methods, callback, delegates

I have two classes DetailViewController and FactTableViewController. I want to call the method reloadData in the DetailViewController from the FactTableViewController. The following code compiles and executes but reloadData is never called from the FactTableViewController.

```
DetailViewController.m
//....
-(void) reloadData
{
    //code to refresh data
    NSLog(@"reloadData");
}

FactTableViewController.h
#import "DetailViewController.h"
//...

FactTableViewController.m
@interface FactTableViewController()
@property (assign,nonatomic) DetailViewController *delegate;
@end

@implementation FactTableViewController
//...
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
//...
@end

//...
-(void) doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *) sendor
{
      NSLog(@"doneButton pressed"); //this gets called
      [_delegate performSelector:@selector(reloadData)]; //this does not get called
}

//...
```

Comment: How are you instantiating `DetailViewController *delegate`?

Comment: Note: `@synthesize` is not needed, has not been needed for several years. Also Xcode does not call anything, it is an IDE (Fancy code editor).

Comment: I am new to ios development and *delegate is not getting init. Should *delegate be instantiated with: delegate = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer. Thanks for the advice above I initialized delegate to DetailViewController and it now works.